# Compiling a c++ including root libraries with g++

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, root-framework

I am trying to compile a c++ program, which uses the TF1 library of the ROOT-framework, with the g++ compiler.

I tried

I already tried

```
g++ a.cpp -o 'root-config --cflags --glibs'
```

But that just gives me the error

```
g++: error: no such file or directory: 'root-config --cflags --glibs'
```

I am very new to both ROOT and C++ so help is very mucha appreciated!

Comment: I don't know ROOT but I can tell you that `'root-config --cflags glibs'` is definitely a command, but the `-o` is trying to interpret it as an output file. To produce an executable you'll have to specify a file name like `-o a`.

Comment: in addition to what @jwilson says, single quotes `'` just mark a string literal and won't call the `root-config` program. (which is essentially what the error message says). subprocesses are called with backticks `, or (like in the answer below) with dollar and parentheses (often preferable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478 or http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Answer (score 2):

You must check with:

```
g++ a.cpp $(root-config --cflags --glibs) -o a
```

Comment: Now it compiles. Thank you very much! But now it just won't show me the graph that I created with ```f1->Draw()```, it just tells me via the bash. Do you know how to fix that too?

Comment: You are welcome :). Sorry, I do not know that (I am not a root user).

Comment: @TwoStones do you keep the application alive somehow? Of course once your program terminates (eg by returning from `main`) any windows get closed

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thats probably the problem. But how do I keep the program from returning from ```main```? Sorry for these kind of questions, I am just very new to this

Comment: @TwoStones try to put a `int dummy; std::cin >> dummy;` at the end, then it wait for you to type something and press enter

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Ok, but it still doesnt show me my graph :/ It just puts on hold until I enter something.

Comment: @TwoStone maybe open another question

Comment: for using graphics in a compiled application see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/36341590/4588453